# TF237090: Does not exist or access is denied

Tags: workitem

I created a new work item type, i'm trying to import it in my tfs 2012 project but i'm getting  an error *TF237090: Does not exist or access is denied*. I can succesfully import an existing workitem after changes but not a new one.

Comment: Dumb question: does your user have required permissions?

Comment: yes i have all the permissions. i can edit an existing work item type and import it, but i can't a new one.

Comment: Check the time on the TFS Server.  Similar problem here suggests the system clock could be at fault: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/a8910b4f-0248-44de-8edb-3d97823239e9

Comment: I have already read this post and i check the server time, and it is the same. thanks anyway

Comment: What is the command line you are using to import it?

Comment: Is anything misspelled in the URL or project? You seem to have changed the names, so check for things like http:// being there and for any characters being incorrect. This is the most likely issue of you have permissions.

Comment: It won't work without the http:// in the collection URL.  Also you should try specifying the full path to the AWBug.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in VS2012 by importing WIT via the Dev Studio Tools->Process Editor->Work Item Types->Import WIT. If I recall when I ran into this issue before it was because someone had the a work item open (in this case it was a test case).

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

- Ensure that the version of `witadmin` being used for import & export of WITDs corresponds with the TFS Server version
- Ensure that the version of the [MS VS TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=visual%20studio%20team%20foundation%20server%20power%20tools&f%5B1%5D.Value=visual%20studio%20team%20foundation%20server%20power%20tools&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=tools&f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&ac=5) being used corresponds to the TFS Server version

**Background**

I have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed, including versions 2012 (v11.0), and 2013 (v12.0). However, our TFS Server version is 2012.

I had this problem when running [`witadmin importwitd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) from the command line. It seems that the tools used to export and import the Work Item Type Definitions (WITDs) need to be the same as the TFS server version. Hence, when running from the command line, for running with TFS 2012, the `witadmin` command should be run from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` directory, not the `v12.0` or any other version.

Once I realized that I may have been trying to import a WITD XML file that had been exported from a different `witadmin` version, I re-exported (from the server) in the correct version - use `witadmin exportwitd` - then made my changes, and re-imported.

One annoyance is that the Work Item Type Editor for 2012 didn't seem to care that the XML WITD file that I imported came from a different version.

Insight gained from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/399b4c50-fbaa-43f6-a0f5-88129f9b2ed8/tf237090-does-not-exist-or-access-is-denied-when-usint-witadmin-importwitd?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: witadmin is backwards compatible, so you should be able to import WITDs to the older version of TFS using newer version of VS. If you see an error, it means there's a bug, this scenario is supported and should just work.

Comment: @OlegMikhaylov I wish that was my experience. All I know is that when I exported and re-imported after making the same changes, but with the v11 tool (instead of v12), that it worked again. I didn't notice any version flags or anything else that might impact this.

Comment: If you see this problem again, feel free to contact me. I'm on the TFS product team and can try to help.

Comment: @OlegMikhaylov - Thanks Oleg. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to change the Task WIT template of a particular project using [TFS Process Template Editor Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) in Visual Studio 2017, but when attempting to change another project it was failing with message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Failed to save the 'Task' Work Item Type to the server.**TF237090**: Does not exist or access is denied.

I am a member Project Collection Administrators (at higher level - collection) and I had most of the permissions needed to perform most of the changes required, including Team Admin ('Team Project Name' Team - Administrators).

Turns out that I was not part of the 'Project Administrators' within that particular team project. All I had to do was to navigate to the Admin area, under Security tab of that particular project and add my username to the Project Administrators group.